# ReactNative - No crash report in release mode sentry.io

Tags: react-native, sentry, cartalyst-sentry

Successfully integrated the sentry.io.

In one of the componet in constructor I have placed a console.log() with invalid variable.

whenever I run using `react-native run-ios` or `react-native run-android` it is reported in sentry.io dashboard. *(debug mode)*

But if I build the apk in release mode using `cd android && ./gradlew assemblerelease` It doesn't catches any crash.

Comment: This question will likely get no good answers until you provide some code around your configuration for Sentry.io

Comment: We recently had something like this on the forum
https://forum.sentry.io/t/added-to-react-native-app-not-reporting-any-crashes/2718

Please notice that crashes will be sent after the next app start.

Comment: No, I waited for a day but nothing showed up in the dashboards.